# Querying by "_id" doesn't return file in MongoDB in Python, using PyMongo

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I'm using Python + MongoDB + PyMongo in Openshift

```
import os
import gridfs
from django.http import HttpResponse
from pymongo.connection import Connection
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, RequestContext,loader

connection = Connection('mongodb://sbose78:XXXXXX@staff.mongohq.com:10068/BOSE')
db=connection['BOSE']
fs=gridfs.GridFS(db)
```

When I query a file by _id, this is what I get.

```
>>> fs.exists({"_id":'504a36d93324f20944247af2'})
False
```

When I query with the corresponding filename:

```
>>> fs.exists({"filename":'foo.txt'})

True
```

What could be possibly be going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For pymongo versions < 2.2, you need to import ObjectId with

```
from pymongo.objectid import ObjectId
```

For versions 2.2 and above, the import is instead

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
```

Then you can query gridfs like so:

```
fs.exists(ObjectId('504a36d93324f20944247af2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fs.exists({"_id":ObjectId('504a36d93324f20944247af2')})
```

You need to use `ObjectId`

Comment: I'm getting this
NameError: name 'ObjectID' is not defined.

Comment: Its working for me here. Can you show all of your code here please.

Comment: Edited the question description with the imports Vivek.

Comment: I wanted to see if you are getting the object id correct. Can you show the code to get the object id?

Comment: No no. Let mongo generate ObjectIds. When you put/write object into the mongo db through gridfs, you'll get an object id. Use that.